# 1940 Buick Super brake master cylinder removal

Tags: brakes, buick

I have a 1940 Buick Super. I need to remove the master cylinder to rebuild it, but the bolts turn in the frame when I try to  remove the nuts. There is some kind of metal cover over the end of the bolt and no head to grip.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the nuts on threaded studs, you can use a nut splitter to get the nuts off. Then you can clean up the threads, and you might have access to the blind side of the mounting point.

[image]